# center bottom right and bottom left

Tags: css

```html
 <div class="the-images"> 
      <img id="item1" class="item" src="" alt="Item 1"> 
      <div id="credit1">CREDIT1</div>
      <img id="item2" class="item" src="" alt="Item 2"> 
      <div id="credit2">CREDIT2</div>
  </div>
```

Okay lets say these `.item`'s are both 50-50 `vw` how would i make `#credit1` centered on bottom right of the `item1` and `#credit2` on bottom left of the `item2`

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you.

I have used `flex` and `position` property to solve your problem. you can also change horizontal alignment of **#credit** by modify the `text-align` value as per your need(center/left/right).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.the-images {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.the-images .item {
  width: 50vw;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.the-images #credit1,
.the-images #credit2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 50vw;
  padding: 4px;
}

.the-images #credit1 {
  left: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.the-images #credit2 {
  left: 50vw;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="the-images">
  <img id="item1" class="item" src="https://placehold.co/600x400" alt="Item 1">
  <div id="credit1">CREDIT1</div>
  <img id="item2" class="item" src="https://placehold.co/600x400" alt="Item 2">
  <div id="credit2">CREDIT2</div>
</div>
```